# React + Firebase "sign-in provider disabled" despite it being enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, create-react-app

In my Authentication -> Sign-in Method - it's Email & Password set to 'Enabled'.

I have a handler for an onSubmit calling this:

```
createUser(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = this.createEmail.value
    const password = this.createPassword.value
    const confirm = this.confirmPassword.value
    if(password === confirm) {
        firebase.auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((res) => {
                this.showCreate(e)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(error.message)
            })
    }
    else {
        alert('Passwords must match')
    }
}
```

And it shoots this error "The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section."

I'm using the firebase npm package. It's a note-taking application and it's successfully communicating with the database.

But I have it Enabled. Is anyone aware of how to fix this, or if there's a setting I seem to be missing?

SOLUTION: I fixed this by removing the environment variable and using the raw API string. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing the environment variable and using the raw API string.